# How can I create a auto executer module in zend frame work?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, reminders

I have a module in zend framework and I want to execute it as per database date time value difference. You can think that I want to create a birth day reminder which will display a message to my users on his birth day. How can i create it in zend framework? any suggestion or any idea is mostly welcome.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to get the date time and the time zone difference from the database (probably using a model).

Then you can use gmstrftime() if the time zone difference is in numeric representation (eg. +1, +2 or -1, -2 etc) :

```
<?php
    $offset = 2;
    $timestamp = time() + ( $offset * 60 * 60 );
    echo gmstrftime("%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S", $timestamp) . "\n";
?>
```

PHP Manual here - http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmstrftime.php

But a more elegant solution could be to use DateTime::setTimezone():

```
<?php
// From PHP manual 

$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Chatham'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
?>
```